# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object on passport after createToken()

Tags: laravel, restful-authentication, laravel-passport

when i using passport package After doing this,

```
$success['token'] =  $users->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
```

I'll deal with error in this code :

```
  protected function createRequest($client, $userId, array $scopes)
{
    return (new ServerRequest)->withParsedBody([
        'grant_type' => 'personal_access',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'scope' => implode(' ', $scopes),
    ]);
}
```

text of error :

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

why clinet variabale has null ??

Comment: Please include the code where you're defining `$client` because the issue is that `$client` -- whatever that is -- does not have the `id` assigned.

Comment: Where is `createRequest()` defined?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when i upgraded to ^3.0. I ran php artisan passport:install --force to regenerate keys and it worked.

Comment: Before updating passport, try the command `php artisan passport:install --force`